# Maximal subgroup disjoint with rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, direct-sum

I struggle with the following theorem: given an abelian group $(G,+)$ such that $\mathbb{Q} < G$, show that if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ such that $H\cap \mathbb{Q} = \{ 0 \}$, then $G = \mathbb{Q}\oplus H$.

I think that we only need the fact that these are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module (to use Baer's criterion). However, I get stuck on the details. Can you prove this theorem?

Answer (score 3):

You already have a direct sum since the intersection is zero. Now if you were to take $g \in G \setminus \mathbb{Q} \oplus H$ you could consider $K = \mathbb{Z} g \oplus H$ which contradicts the maximality of $H$:
Take $mg +h \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $m$  non zero. You have $a=(mg+h)/m \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $a- g = \in \mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}g \leq G$ and $ma = h \in H$.
Consider $H' = H + \mathbb{Z} a$, by maximality, $H' = H$, so $a \in H$.
We thus have $m(g + a) = mg + h \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $g+a \in \mathbb{Q}$ thus $g \in \mathbb{Q} \oplus H$ which is absurd. Thus $G =  \mathbb{Q} \oplus H$.

Is it more clear now?

Comment: What is $m^{-1}$? $m$ is some integer. Also, I think that your argument skips the difficult details. For example, if we have $mg + h = q \neq 0$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then for some $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $mg + h = mp$. Even if there is $h'\in H$ such that $mh' = h$, then we get $m(g + h' - p) = 0$ which does not imply a priori that $g + h' - p = 0$.

Comment: The point is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and $m=0$ implies $h=0$ and we don’t want to study null elements of the sum $\mathbb{Z}g \oplus H$. I did not detail it too much for a reason: I think we should not do it on this site unless it is requested if the “student” does not get the point. Maybe you should try to tell me more about your condition $\mathbb{Q} < G$; is $G$ a subgroup of some bigger group like $\mathbb{R}$? Or is there an injective and not surjective group morphisme from $Q$ to $G$?

Comment: $G$ is any abelian group containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subgroup. I have pointed out very specific parts in your proof that I think require further explanation, could you please elaborate on them?

Comment: Ok but to have $Q$ as a subgroup you have to be a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ that’s what I meant

Comment: That's not true. Take any extension of $\mathbb{C}$ of bigger cardinality, it is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It depends on your definition, in this case you should say that $G$ is a group extension rather than $Q$ is a subgroup